# How to print this pattern using Tuples?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I am new to Python Tuples, and doing a learning exercise on the same. How should I print the following pattern when the input is the String HI,HELLO,WELCOME.

```
(('HI', 'HELLO', 'WELCOME'),) 
((('HI', 'HELLO', 'WELCOME'),),) 
(((('HI', 'HELLO', 'WELCOME'),),),)
```

**My Attempt**

```
n = input()
arr = tuple(raw_input().split())
arr1 = list()
print arr
while(n>0) :
    print(tuple(arr,))
    n -= 1
```

Comment: Is getting the input from the user part of the exercise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just define (or create) a `tuple` at start, then nest it on itself (reusing the same variable):

```
n = 3
arr = ('HI','HELLO','WELCOME')  # or tuple(raw_input().split())

while(n>0):
    arr = (arr,)  # that's enough to create a tuple inside the tuple
    print(arr)
    n -= 1
```

result:

```
(('HI', 'HELLO', 'WELCOME'),)
((('HI', 'HELLO', 'WELCOME'),),)
(((('HI', 'HELLO', 'WELCOME'),),),)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks . I didn't knew that tuple can be reassigned to itself.

Comment: everything can be reassigned to itself :)

Comment: Actually, this is enough ;-) `tup = tup,`. One could argue however that the parenthesis add clarity.

Comment: @ChristianDean at first my answer had `tuple((arr,))` :) but that's true. Leaving that to your answer

Answer (score 2):

Just nest your first tuple in another tuple each iteration.

```
>>> n = 3
>>> tup = ('HI', 'HELLO', 'WELCOME')
>>> for _ in range(n):
    tup = tup,
    print(tup)


(('HI', 'HELLO', 'WELCOME'),)
((('HI', 'HELLO', 'WELCOME'),),)
(((('HI', 'HELLO', 'WELCOME'),),),)
>>>
```

As you can see, on each iteration the tuple is nested a level deeper. The problem with your original method is that you didn't reassign the new nested tuple back to `arr`, so your tuple's never nested.

Answer (score 0):

In your attempt you were always printing the same thing. You need to update the tuple on each iteration, so you have to have

```
while n>0:
    arr = (arr,)
    print(arr)
    n=-1
```